# bitwise and and bit strings in Spark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have noticed that the Spark SQL data frames have methods for bitwise AND, OR, XOR. These operations seem to me very useful, if using a bit string. However, so far I haven't found a possibility to have a BitSet column (I guess I could create an integer column, but that would be limited to 32 bits).

How could I create a ("long", i.e. more than 64 bits) BitSet that can be used with the bitwise operations given by the dataframe?